# GridView not returning databound rows when OnClick event fires

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that is made up of two database fields populated via a stored procedure and then three fields for user input (two checkbox controls and one textbox) when I click on the save button I can get the information from the three controls but nothing from the two that were populated via the database. How can I get the first two fields?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvA1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="CodeNo" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" EnablePersistedSelection="True" Visible="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CodeNo")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-Width="400px" HeaderText="Violation">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CodeViolationCited") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="A1Accordion_cbPool" runat="server" Text="Pool:" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="A1Accordion_cbSpa" runat="server" Text="Spa:" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Additional Comments" Visible="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="A1Accordion_tb" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void SaveAndCollapseA1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //good stuff
    CheckBox myCheckBox_1 = gvA1.Rows[0].FindControl("A1Accordion_cbPool") as CheckBox;
    CheckBox myCheckBox_2 = gvA1.Rows[0].FindControl("A1Accordion_cbSpa") as CheckBox;
    TextBox myTextBox = gvA1.Rows[0].FindControl("A1Accordion_tb") as TextBox;

    //not so good stuff
    String myString1 = gvA1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
    String myString2 = gvA1.Rows[0].Cells[1].ToString();


}
```

I figured it out but I haven't been hear long enough to post the solution via the links but if you change the columns as so:

```
<asp:label ID="lblA1CodeNo" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("CodeNo") %>'></asp:label>
```

then the values are available...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<%# Bind("CodeViolationCited") %>
```

Instead of

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CodeViolationCited") %>
```

Eval is one way, bind is two-way.

[See Microsoft's documentation for data-binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

Comment: Changing it to a label 'object' made it available... I'm a DBA that was asked to build a web site so... it works I'm moving forward with it :)